# Angular routing is not hitting its route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here i'm new to angularjs please help me why i'm not able to hit my routing. The problem is that when I click on the contact link it's not firing the `.when` function.

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute'])

    app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/Contact', {
            templateUrl: '/ApiClient/Contact/AdminContact.html',
            controller:'ContactCtrl'
        })

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false,
            hashPrefix:''
        });
    })
```

**Html**

```
<div>
        <a href="#!/Contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please tell us what's not working.

Comment: when i click on contact link its not hitting .when('/Contact', {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try for this.

```
<p><a href="#/!">Main</a></p>

<a href="#!Contact">Contact</a> // Actually you put #!/Contact instead of #!Contact

<div ng-view></div>

var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm"
    })
    .when("/Contact", {
        templateUrl: '/ApiClient/Contact/AdminContact.html',
        controller:'ContactCtrl'
    });
});
```

Comment: don't use #!/Contact in your routing, use only #!Contact , this will work

Comment: in the above code, line no 2, i put // for comment, where u did, that a minor mistake

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
<a href="#!Contact">Contact</a>
```

not

```
<a href="#!/Contact">Contact</a>
```

Comment: this is <a href="#!/Contact">Contact</a>  not working

Comment: @MdGhousemohi remove the / should be #!Contact